# Is there any document for Delphi+Firebird from the very beginning (Server Side)

Tags: delphi, document, firebird

I want to code a server side software with Delphi+Firebird but i need a documentation (or tutorial) that explains all the steps and components from the beginning. Is there any site/tutorial/document that you can suggest? which explains step by step coding.

Even if you suggest a component to make server side connection with regard to your experiences, i will be glad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The main English information source for Firebird is [IBPhoenix](http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&s=1292063514:200606&page=ibp_document).
2. The main Russian information source for Firebird is [IBase](http://www.ibase.ru/).
3. The [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq7/) gives a list of Delphi connectivity options and answers on many other Firebird questions.
4. It will be hard to pass along [IBExpert](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/). There you will find useful tools and Firebird articles.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Firebird is a fork from Interbase, yes Interbase had become an open source some time ago and then become closed source again. So, u can use Interbase as a reference. But as time goes, Firebird become better and better in quality. Also become different from Interbase itself. To get more info on Firebird, u can visit www.ibphoenix.com. 
For the components to connect Firebird, u can use FIBPlus, UIB, anyDac, UNIDAC and many more. The one u must avoid is IBX itself, Jeff Overcash has state that IBX is NEVER tested against Firebird and WILL NOT TESTED agains Firebird. They see Firebird as competitor actually. 
I use Firebird daily and it never fails (except if your HDD broken).

Comment: We use IBX with Firebird for 10 years and it works just fine.

Comment: We've used IBX with Firebird 2.1 in Delphi 7 in production software for a long long time. It certainly works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is a weak side of Firebird server. We usually use a combination of:

1. Interbase documentation
2. Firebird release notes
3. Information from Firebird forums
4. Helen Borrie's Firebird book

Delphi uses pretty unified technology to talk to any server be it Firebird or not. So, there is just enough information you could find in a help or in available books.

Comment: Helen's book is very useful, and it also adds credibility to the "open source database" in the eyes of management because there's a professionally published reference book (*smile*) available...!